# Почему grep не понимает экранирущую последовательность \n?

Tags: grep

Использую grep с флагом -P, с помощью которого grep обрабатывает регулярное выражения как PCRE. Но команда не понимает перенос строки (\n), хотя в то же время поддерживает другие экранирующие последовательности, например, такие как: \s (правда, она видит его как пробел только), \w, \d. Можно ли как-то заставить grep понимать \n?

Comment: Он его понимает так, как и должен. И, скорее, проблема не в нем :)

Comment: grep то вообще то построчный. Я знаю трюк с трактованием всего текста как бинарной строки, тогда перевод строки отрабатывает, но это не то, что нужно использовать в каждодневной практике. Установите себе ack или ag - они "из коробки" умеют перловые регулярки и многострочный поиск.

Answer (score 2):

grep работает построчно. По умолчанию строки разделяются новой строкой `'\n'`.

В качестве хака, можно заставить grep воспринимать весь текстовый файл как одну большую строчку, если передать флаг `-z` (данные заканчиваются нулевым байтом вместо новой строки (`'\n'`)), например,

```
$ grep -Pzo '(?sm)multiline pattern'
```

Не все версии grep поддерживают `-z` флаг.